# Super with Multiple Inheritance and pytest yields TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I am running into some issues with multiple inheritance using pytest and @classmethod decorator. I cannot figure out what is going wrong and could use some help.

```
import unittest

class HelperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_a_value(self):
        self.x = 1

class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase, HelperClass):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        super(HelperClass, cls).__init__()

        cls.set_a_value()

    def test_something(self):
        assert(self.x == 1)

TestSuite()
```

Error I am getting:

```
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'object' object needs an argument
```

Comment: Why are you calling a different method than the one you're in using super? Why do you need it at all? Just remove the pointless definition in HelperClass.

Comment: It's just a simplified example. The helper class has lots of methods used by multiple test suites. Otherwise, I'd do just that.

Comment: But does it actually shadow `__init__`? And, if so, how would calling it from setUpClass help?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about shadowing. It helps because setupclass runs before the test suite so imagine the helper class has functions like login to a website or create a resource. Maybe I'm going down the wrong path here

Comment: I think you are. As a rule, you use super to call up the chain to the next implementation of the current method. Also you're talking about class methods but `__init__` is used to set up an *instance* (and you seem to be mixing up class and instance generally, as `set_a_value` is an instance method).